# Call method from class "x", given a string that equals "x"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a series of classes, each with methods of the same names, but different functions. I'm wondering how I can reference the needed class in the form of a string as it is based on user input.

Something like this... (I know this doesn't work, it gets the idea across though)

Scenario A:

```
String userinput = "Duck"

int result = "Duck".feed(parameter A);
```

Scenario B:

```
String userinput = "Dog"

int result = "Dog".feed(parameter A);
```

Hypothetically there are >20 classes, and the one needed can only be determined from the string.

Comment: Yes. This can be done using reflection. You need to get that class and call `newInstance()` on it. You will get an instance of it. Then you can call any method in it

Comment: Don't use reflection. Avoid bad habits and read up on inheritance, polymorphism and the factory method pattern.

Comment: You could use a `Map<String, BaseClass>`, where `BaseClass` is the base class with the `feed` method (implemented by subclasses). You then call `yourMap.get("Dog").feed(parameter)`. Otherwise you'll have to use reflection.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Reflection in itself is not bad habit.  In many cases, it's the only possible solution.  Inheritance and polymorphism are good, however factory method with 20 `if` statements is bad, as it's difficult to extend.  You will have to remember to modify your factory every time you add a new class.  Depending on the specifics (and I'm not saying yes or no in this case), inheritance may be a better solution.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Agreed. Factory Method is indeed the *right approach* here.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - He could technically create a *Map* like Backslash suggests. I could change my answer to do that (I just wanted to show the OP that this is possible). Yes, it makes more sense to have a common interface for all classes and use polymorphism :)

Comment: @TheLostMind The `Map` approach is similar to factory method but not really since it'll always return the same object per entry (I don't think Java supports delegates yet that can return a new object per call). Still, though, it's only part of the answer of course (for reasons lined out in my comment on the answer). I do agree that reflection has its uses for an extensible architecture but I have a hunch that this doesn't apply here for OP :-)

Comment: @AleksG what is the bad in the factory? You can just throw an exception that there is no implementation for this class. This is an error that must be caught while you develop

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Yes, you are right. That's why I deleted my answer. It was *err bad* :P. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieve using reflection Class.forName("full class name with package name").newInstance();

Scenario: If you have two class such as "dog" and "cat" and both has same method like eat then create an interface "animal" with eat method

```
class dog implements animal{public void eat(){System.out.println("dog is eating");}}

class cat implements animal{public void eat(){System.out.println("cat is eating");}}

class test{
public static void main(String arg[]){
    String input = "dog";
    animal testAnimal = null;

    try{
        testAnimal = Class.forName(input).newInstance();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}}
```

I hope it should help you with your problem

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much! I was not familiar with interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result; 
  if(userinput.equals("Duck")){

     Duck duck = new Duck(); 
     result = duck.feed(parameter A); 
  }
  else if(userinput.equals("Dog")){ 
     Dog dog = new Dog(); 
     result = dog.feed(parameter A);

}else{
   //default message
}

// do what you want to do with result
```

Comment: Thanks for the response though I'm aware of how if/else statements work, I was really just looking for a way to index a lot of classes based on the content of a string directly.